# How to use HyperLedger Composer Node Sdk?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am working on hyper ledger composer based project. I am writing chain code using javascript.
But I do not want to use automated generated rest server APIs to submit transactions, assets etc.
Can we develop own API in the node to interact with the network?
How?
Please share any code sample or link or any description about this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-restful-api-server-for-hyperledger-fabric-with-nodejs-sdk-a4642edaf98e) article should help to get you started, along with the [Hyperledger Fabric SDK documentation](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.3/index.html).

The article referenced above was literally the third result when I Googled "hyperledger api rest server example" (and the first result on duckduckgo). Please put at least a minimal amount of effort into research before asking a question.